# In cloudformation, can you import api key from another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-key

I'm thinking of deploying my infrastructure on multiple regions but I want the clients to be able to use the same AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey regardless of region.

Can you import AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey from another region?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS SSM Parameter Key store to store your api kay and reference that in your template like: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/